# Concentration-compactness Lemma

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $N\geq 3$ y $2^{*} := 2N/(N - 2)$.
The space $\mathcal{D}^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N) := \left\lbrace u \in L^{2^{*}} (\mathbb{R}^N) : \nabla u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)\right\rbrace $, with the inner product $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \nabla u\nabla v$, and the corresponding norm $\left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |\nabla u|^2\right)^{1/2} $.

The optimal constant in the Sobolev inequality is given by
$$S:= \underset{\begin{matrix}u\in\mathcal{D}^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N)\\ |u|_{2^*}=1\end{matrix}}{\inf} |\nabla u|_{2}^{2}>0.$$
Concentration-compactness Lemma: Let $\left\lbrace u_n\right\rbrace\subset \mathcal{D}^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ be a sequence such that
$$
\begin{matrix}
u_n\rightharpoonup u & \text{in } \mathcal{D}^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N),\\
|\nabla (u_n - u)|^2 \rightharpoonup \mu & \text{in } \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^N),\\
|u_n -u|^{2^{*}}\rightharpoonup \nu & \text{in } \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^N),\\
u_n\rightarrow u & \text{a.e. on } \mathbb{R}^N,
\end{matrix}
$$and define
$$
\mu_\infty :=\lim_{R\to\infty} \limsup_{n\to\infty} \int_{|x|\geq R} |\nabla u_n|^2\, ,\qquad \nu_\infty :=\lim_{R\to\infty} \limsup_{n\to\infty} \int_{|x|> R} | u_n|^{2^{*}}\, .
$$
Then it follows that
$$
||\nu||^{2/2^{*}} \leq S^{-1}||\mu|| ,
$$$$
\nu_{\infty}^{2/2^{*}} \leq S^{-1} \mu_{\infty},
$$$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} |\nabla u_n |_{2}^{2}= |\nabla u|_{2}^{2}+||\mu|| + \mu_{\infty},
$$$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} | u_n |_{2^{*}}^{2^{*}}= |u|_{2^{*}}^{2^{*}}+||\nu|| + \nu_{\infty}.
$$Moreover, if $u=0$ and $||\nu||^{2/2^{*}} = S^{-1}||\mu|| $, then $\nu$ and $\mu$ are concentrated
at a single point.

Proof:

1. Assume first $u = 0$. Choosing $h \in\mathcal{D} (\mathbb{R}^N )$, we infer from the Sobolev inequality that $\{ u_n\}$
   $$\left( \int |hu_n|^{2^{*}}\, dx\right) ^{2/2^{*}}\leq S^{-1} \int |\nabla (hu_n)|^{2}\, dx .$$
   Then
   $$\mid \| \nabla (hu_n)\|_{2} -\| h\nabla u_n\|_{2}\mid \,\leq \|u_n \nabla h\|_2$$
   Taking $\text{supp}(\nabla h)\subseteq K $, we have
   $$\int_{K} |u_n \nabla h|^2\; dx \,\leq \|\nabla h\| \int_K |u_n|^2 dx\rightarrow 0$$
   since $u_n \to 0$ en $L_{loc}^2$.
   Therefore we can write the inequality as
   $$\left( \int |hu_n|^{2^{*}}\, dx\right) ^{2/2^{*}}\leq S^{-1} \int |h(\nabla u_n)|^{2}\, dx .$$
   We would now like to consider $\mu$ and $\nu$. We have as hypothesis
   $$|\nabla (u_n - u)|^2 \rightharpoonup \mu\;\;\text{en}\;\;\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^N),$$
   $$|u_n -u|^{2^{*}}\rightharpoonup \nu\;\;\text{en}\;\;\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^N).$$
   Combining the above results, we can rewrite the equation as
   \begin{equation}
   \left( \int |h|^{2^{*}}\, d\nu \right) ^{2/2^{*}}\leq S^{-1} \int |h|^{2}\, d\mu .
   \end{equation}
   Then we have t
   \begin{align*}
   \left( \int |h|^{2^{*}}\, d\nu \right) ^{2/2^{*}}&\;\leq\; S^{-1} \int |h|^{2}\, d\mu \\
   \underset{\begin{matrix} |h|_{\infty}=1 \end{matrix}}{\sup} |\left\langle \nu , h\right\rangle |^{2/2^{*}} &\;\leq\; S^{-1} \underset{\begin{matrix} |h|_{\infty}=1 \end{matrix}}{\sup} |\left\langle \mu , h\right\rangle | \\
   \| \nu\|^{2/2^{*}}&\;\leq\;S^{-1}\|\mu\|
   \end{align*}
   Therefore, the first inequality is verified.
2. For $R > 1$, let$\psi_R \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^ N )$ be such that $\psi_R (x) = 1$ for $|x| > R+ 1$, $\psi_R (x) = 0$ for $|x| < R$ and $0\leq\psi_R (x)\leq 1$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$. By the Sobolev inequality, we have
   \begin{equation}
   S^{1/2}\|\psi_R u_n\|_{2^{*}}\leq \|\nabla(\psi_R u_n)\|_2 \leq\|\nabla u_n \psi_R \|_2 +\| u_n\nabla \psi_R\|_2
   \end{equation}
   or in other words
   $$ S^{1/2}\left( \int |\psi_R u_n|^{2^{*}}\, dx \right) ^{1/2^{*}}\leq \left( \int |\nabla u_n  |^{2}|\psi_R |^{2}\, dx\right) ^{1/2} + \left( \int | u_n|^{2}|\nabla \psi_R |^{2}\, dx\right)^{1/2} .$$
   Then
   $$\mid \| \nabla (\psi_R u_n)\|_{2} -\| \psi_R\nabla u_n\|_{2}\mid \,\leq \|u_n \nabla \psi_R \|_2$$
   Taking $\text{supp}(\nabla \psi_R)\subseteq K $, we have
   $$\int_{K} |u_n \nabla \psi_R|^2\; dx \,\leq \|\nabla \psi_R\|_\infty \int_K |u_n|^2 dx\rightarrow 0$$
   since $u_n \to 0$ en $L_{loc}^2$.
   Therefore we can write the inequality as
   $$\left( \int |\psi_R u_n|^{2^{*}}\, dx\right) ^{2/2^{*}}\leq S^{-1} \int |\psi_R(\nabla u_n)|^{2}\, dx .$$
   Taking the superior limit on both sides of the inequality, the following is obtained
   \begin{multline}
   \limsup_{n\to\infty}\left( \int |\psi_R u_n|^{2^{*}}\, dx \right) ^{2/2^{*}}\leq S^{-1} \left( \limsup_{n\to\infty}\int | u_n|^{2}|\nabla\psi_R|^{2}\, dx\right)  .
   \end{multline}

In addition, we have
$$\int_{|x|> R+1} |\nabla u_n|^{2}\, dx\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |\nabla u_n|^{2}\psi_R^{2}\, dx\leq \int_{|x|>R} |\nabla u_n|^{2}\, dx$$
y
$$\int_{|x|> R+1} | u_n|^{2^{*}}\, dx\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} | u_n|^{2^{*}}\psi_R^{2^{*}}\, dx\leq \int_{|x|>R} |u_n|^{2^{*}}\, dx$$
Taking the limit when  $R\to\infty$, we have that by hypothesis are defined as
$$
\mu_\infty :=\lim_{R\to\infty} \limsup_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |\nabla u_n|^2\psi_R^{2}\, dx,$$
$$ \nu_\infty :=\lim_{R\to\infty} \limsup_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} | u_n|^{2^{*}}\psi_R^{2^{*}}\, dx .
$$
Combining the above results
\begin{align*}
\lim_{R\to\infty} \limsup_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} | u_n|^{2^{*}}\psi_R^{2^{*}}\, dx &\leq S^{-1}\lim_{R\to\infty} \limsup_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |\nabla u_n|^2\psi_R^{2}\, dx\\
\nu_\infty \;\;&\leq S^{-1}\;\; \mu_\infty 
\end{align*}

Verifying that $\nu_{\infty}^{2/2^{*}} \leq S^{-1} \mu_{\infty}$.

3. Now we want to see that $\nu$ is concentrated at a single point. For this let us further assume that $||\nu||^{2/2^{*}} = S^{-1}||\mu|| $.
   From Holder's inequality for $h \in\mathcal{D} (\mathbb{R}^N )$, and combined with $\left( \int |h|^{2^{*}}\, d\nu \right) ^{2/2^{*}}\leq S^{-1} \int |h|^{2}\, d\mu .$
   \begin{equation*}
   \left( \int |h|^{2^{*}}\, d\nu \right) ^{1/2^{*}}\leq S^{-1/2}||\mu||^{1/N} \left(\int |h|^{2^{*}}\, d\mu \right) ^{1/2^{*}}.
   \end{equation*}
   It follows that $\nu \leq S^{-2^{*}/2}||\mu||^{2/N-2}\mu$. If we combine it with
   $||\nu||^{2/2^{*}} = S^{-1}||\mu|| $ we have
   $$\nu = S^{-2^{*}/2}||\mu||^{2/N-2}\mu$$
   and
   $$\mu = S||\nu||^{-2/N}\nu.$$

From $\left( \int |h|^{2^{*}}\, d\nu \right) ^{2/2^{*}}\leq S^{-1} \int |h|^{2}\, d\mu $ we have that, for $h \in\mathcal{D} (\mathbb{R}^N )$,
\begin{equation*}
\left( \int |h|^{2^{*}}\, d\nu \right) ^{2/2^{*}}\leq \int |h|^{2}\, ||\nu||^{-2/N}d\nu ,
\end{equation*}
i.e.
\begin{equation*}
\left( \int |h|^{2^{*}}\, d\nu \right) ^{1/2^{*}}||\nu||^{1/N}\leq \left(\int |h|^{2}\, d\nu \right) ^{1/2},
\end{equation*}
and so on, for each open set $\Omega$
$$\nu(\Omega)^{1/2^{*}}\nu(\mathbb{R}^N)^{1/N}\leq \nu(\Omega)^{1/2}.$$
Then $\nu(\Omega)=0$ or $\nu(\mathbb{R}^N)\leq \nu(\Omega)$.
It follows that $\nu$  is concentrated in a single point.

4. Considering now the general case, we write $v_n := u_n - u$. Since
   $$v_n \rightharpoonup 0, \,\, \text{en } \mathcal{D}^{1,2} (\mathbb{R}^N )$$
   we have
   $$|\nabla u_n|^{2}\rightharpoonup \mu +|\nabla u|^{2} \,\, \text{in } \mathcal{M} (\mathbb{R}^N ).$$
   According to the Brezis-Lieb Lemma, we have for every non negative  $h \in\mathcal{K} (\mathbb{R}^N )$
   $$\int h|u|^{2^{*}}\, = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \int h|u_n|^{2^{*}}-\int h|v_n|^{2^{*}}\right) .$$
   Hence we obtain
   $$| u_n|^{2^{*}}\rightharpoonup \nu +| u|^{2^{*}} \,\, \text{in } \mathcal{M} (\mathbb{R}^N ).$$
   Inequality $||\nu||^{2/2^{*}} \leq S^{-1}||\mu||$ follows from the corresponding inequality for $\{v_n\}$.
5. Since
   $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int_{|x|> R} |\nabla v_n|^{2}\,= \limsup_{n\to\infty}\int_{|x|> R} |\nabla u_n|^{2}- \int_{|x|> R} |\nabla u|^{2}$$
   we obtain
   $$\lim_{R\to\infty}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int_{|x|> R} |\nabla v_n|^{2}=\mu_\infty .$$
   By the Brezis-Lieb Lemma, we have
   $$\int_{|x|> R} |u|^{2^{*}}\, = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \int_{|x|> R} |u_n|^{2^{*}}-\int_{|x|> R} |v_n|^{2^{*}}\right) .$$
   and so
   $$\lim_{R\to\infty}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int_{|x|\geq R} | v_n|^{2^{*}}=\nu_\infty .$$
   Inequality $\nu_{\infty}^{2/2^{*}} \leq S^{-1} \mu_{\infty}$ follows then from the corresponding inequality for $\{v_n\}$.
6. For every $R > 1$, we have
   \begin{equation*}
   \begin{split}
   \limsup_{n\to\infty}\int |\nabla u_n|^{2} & = \limsup_{n\to\infty}\left( \int \psi_{R}|\nabla u_n|^{2} +  \int (1-\psi_{R})|\nabla u_n|^{2}\right) \\
   & = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \int \psi_{R}|\nabla u_n|^{2} \\ &\qquad\quad+  \int (1-\psi_{R})\, d\mu +  \int (1-\psi_{R})|\nabla u|^{2}
   \end{split}
   \end{equation*}
   When $R \to\infty$, we get, by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem
   $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int |\nabla u_n|^{2} =\mu_{\infty} +\int d\mu + \int |\nabla u|^2 = \mu_{\infty} + ||\mu|| + |\nabla u|_{2}^{2}.$$

Now applying Brezis-Lieb's lemma, for $R>1$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int |u_n|^{2^*} & = \limsup_{n\to\infty}\left( \int \psi_{R}|u_n|^{2^*} +  \int (1-\psi_{R})| u_n|^{2^*}\right) \\
& = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \int \psi_{R}|u_n|^{2^*}  \int (1-\psi_{R})\, d\nu +  \int (1-\psi_{R})| u|^{2^*}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
When $R \to\infty$, by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem we get
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int |u_n|^{2^*} = | u|_{2^*}^{2^*} + ||\nu|| +\nu_{\infty} .$$
We have therefore proved $\limsup_{n\to\infty} |\nabla u_n |_{2}^{2}= |\nabla u|_{2}^{2}+||\mu|| + \mu_{\infty}$ and $ \limsup_{n\to\infty} | u_n |_{2^{*}}^{2^{*}}= |u|_{2^{*}}^{2^{*}}+||\nu|| + \nu_{\infty}$.

There are parts I don't understand. My doubts are:
In part 3 of the proof I don't realize how this was obtained:
From Holder's inequality for $h \in\mathcal{D} (\mathbb{R}^N )$, and combined with $\left( \int |h|^{2^{*}}\, d\nu \right) ^{2/2^{*}}\leq S^{-1} \int |h|^{2}\, d\mu .$
\begin{equation*}
\left( \int |h|^{2^{*}}\, d\nu \right) ^{1/2^{*}}\leq S^{-1/2}||\mu||^{1/N} \left(\int |h|^{2^{*}}\, d\mu \right) ^{1/2^{*}}.
\end{equation*}
It follows that $\nu \leq S^{-2^{*}/2}||\mu||^{2/N-2}\mu$.

The same for this part:
\begin{equation*}
\left( \int |h|^{2^{*}}\, d\nu \right) ^{1/2^{*}}||\nu||^{1/N}\leq \left(\int |h|^{2}\, d\nu \right) ^{1/2},
\end{equation*}
and so on, for each open set $\Omega$
$$\nu(\Omega)^{1/2^{*}}\nu(\mathbb{R}^N)^{1/N}\leq \nu(\Omega)^{1/2}.$$

In part 4 of the demonstration I don't realize how this follows:

According to the Brezis-Lieb Lemma, we have for every non negative  $h \in\mathcal{K} (\mathbb{R}^N )$
$$\int h|u|^{2^{*}}\, = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \int h|u_n|^{2^{*}}-\int h|v_n|^{2^{*}}\right) .$$
Hence we obtain
$$| u_n|^{2^{*}}\rightharpoonup \nu +| u|^{2^{*}} \,\, \text{in } \mathcal{M} (\mathbb{R}^N ).$$

In part 6 of the demonstration I don't realize how this is deduced:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int |\nabla u_n|^{2} & = \limsup_{n\to\infty}\left( \int \psi_{R}|\nabla u_n|^{2} +  \int (1-\psi_{R})|\nabla u_n|^{2}\right) \\
& = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \int \psi_{R}|\nabla u_n|^{2} \\ &\qquad\quad+  \int (1-\psi_{R})\, d\mu +  \int (1-\psi_{R})|\nabla u|^{2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
When $R \to\infty$, we get, by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int |\nabla u_n|^{2} =\mu_{\infty} +\int d\mu + \int |\nabla u|^2 = \mu_{\infty} + ||\mu|| + |\nabla u|_{2}^{2}.$$

Comment: Hi! It is nice to see a relatively new user post well-written MathJax and seemingly good math, however it would seem that you are asking quite a few questions at once. It might be better to split them up into their own questions, and to give a bit more detail about what you're not understanding. Have a nice day/night!